# Matlab: Changing properties of another class

Tags: matlab, class, object, oop, interaction

I am working on a simulation of how Particles with magnetic characteristics interact with each other.

I am looking for a way to update the properties of a class from within another class. That's because the properties I'm interested in, only change when there is at least one other particle present.

So my idea was to define a class called Particles with subclasses 'Proton', 'Electron', etc. . But let's focus on Protons for now.

I also defined a class called GroupofParticles, where the input when initializing the object is an Array of Particles

```
classdef Particle < handle
    properties
        location
        magneticmoment
    end

    methods
        % Get-Methoden definieren
        function res = GetLocation(obj)
            if nargin ~= 0
                res = obj.location;
            else
                Error('location is not set yet')
            end
        end

        function res = GetMagneticMoment(obj)
            if nargin ~= 0
                res = obj.magneticmoment;
            else
                Error('Magnetic Moment is not set yet')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

```
classdef Proton < Particle
    properties (Access = private)
        gamma = 2.6752218744 * 10^8             % 1/ (s*T)
        length_mu = 1.41060679736 * 10^(-26)    % J/T
    end
    properties
        ActingBField
    end

    methods
        % Constructor 
        function obj = Proton(location, direction)
            obj.location = location;
            obj.magneticmoment = direction / abs(direction) * obj.length_mu;
            obj.ActingBFeld = zeros(1,3);
        end
    end
end

function res = abs(a)
    res = sqrt(a(1)^2 + a(2)^2 + a(3)^2);
end
```

```
classdef GroupParticles
    properties
        ParticleArray
        DistanceMatrix
    end

    methods
        function obj = GroupParticles(Particles)
            obj.ParticleArray = Particles;
        end
    end
end
```

The idea was to define a method in my class 'GroupofParticles', which changes the properties 'magneticmoment' and 'ActingBField' of my Proton objects.

Is there any way to do this in matlab? If not, then which other ways are there to connect two objects?

Thanks for taking the time. I'm looking forward to reading your answers.

Comment: Did you try the obvious thing? Just modify the property? `particle.ActingBField = ...`

Comment: Thats what I've thought too. However how does the method in my group class know about the attributes of my Particle objects?
Is it possible to write sth like: ```obj.ParticleArray(1,:).ActingBField = ... ```
Will this override the copy created in my group class or change the value in my Particle class as well?

Comment: Unless you mark the properties as private (`Access = private`), they are public, and can be  accessed from anywhere.

Comment: so this means I can save all my particle objects in an array which I declare as an input for an object of another class. Changing the attributes of that array then also changes the attributes of the initial objects?

Comment: First of all, if you want to have different particle types in an array, you need to have the base class inherit from [`matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/heterogeneous-arrays.html). If you also inherit from `handle` (as you're doing) then all copies of the object share their data: changing one of the copies changes them all. So changing the object in `obj.ParticleArray` will also change the original object you stored in there, because they're handles to the same data.

Comment: As I understand it, an array of `Particle` containing different derived types can only be handled like an array of `Particle` objects: you can only access the properties and methods of the base class. But if the array contains only objects of type `Proton`, then you can treat the whole array as `Proton`: you can access the proton properties and methods. So if `obj.ParticleArray(1,:)` are all protons, then you can call proton methods on that, or likewise if `obj.ParticleArray(3,2)` is a proton, then you can call the portion methods on it, and access the proton properties.

Comment: The example on this page might be illuminating: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/using-heterogeneous-class-hierarchies.html

Comment: Thanks, you've been really helpful. I think i know how to implement my algorithm now. 

I was trying to keep my class structures as general as possible since it might be useful to look at other particles except protons later on. They would each share the relevant attributes from the base class ```Particle``` then.

For my ```Proton``` class, I can't think of any methods except for the constructor which might be useful, actually.

Comment: By the way: Instead of redefining `abs` to means something different (changing the meaning of commonly used built-in functions **will** bite you in the butt at some point), use the existing `norm` function.